# How to avoid div animation form going behind relative divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few divs that expand their contained image to resize to a larger size... when hovered. However, when I do so, they go behind the relative divs. I provided a gyazo gif and here is the code.

Thankyou in advance to anyone that can help. I did try messing with the z-index but I had no luck.

https://gyazo.com/13aabe5ecb2763a64f3c215fe207b05a?token=83f00c7326c06866638fdd590f78b9ea

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".temp_thumb_1").mouseenter(function(){ 
   
   
   $("#template_2_wrapper").css({
    "opacity" : '0'
   });
   
   $("#template_1_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
     
   $(".temp_thumb_1").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
  });  
  
  $(".temp_thumb_1").mouseleave(function(){
   
   $("#template_1_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
   $(".temp_thumb_1").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
  });
  
  
  $(".temp_thumb_2").mouseenter(function(){
   
   $("#template_2_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
     
   $(".temp_thumb_2").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
  
   
  });  
  
  $(".temp_thumb_2").mouseleave(function(){
   
   $("#template_2_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
   $(".temp_thumb_2").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
  });
  
  
   $(".temp_thumb_3").mouseenter(function(){
   
   $("#template_3_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
     
   $(".temp_thumb_3").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
  
   
  });  
  
  $(".temp_thumb_3").mouseleave(function(){
   
   $("#template_3_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
   $(".temp_thumb_3").animate({
    "width" : '157px',
    "height" : 'auto'
   });
   
  });
  
 });
```

```css
#templates_sec_1{
 width:76%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#d7d7d7;
 height:200px;
}

#template_1_display, #template_2_display, #template_3_display{
 width:157px;
 height:100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain, cover;
 margin:0 auto;
}
 


#template_1_text_wrapper{
 height:100px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:white;
}

#template_1_hover, #template_2_hover, #template_3_hover{
 width:157px;
 height:200px;
 float:left;
}

.temp_thumb_1, .temp_thumb_2, .temp_thumb_3{
 width:157px;
 height:auto;
}

#template_1_text{
 height:100px;
 width:157px;
 background-color:white;
```

```html
<div id='templates_sec_1'>
 <div id='template_1_hover'>
   <div id='template_1_display'>
    <a href=''><img src='images/template_1_thumbnail.png' class='temp_thumb_1'></a>
   </div>
   <div id='template_1_text'>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id='template_2_hover'>
   <div id='template_2_display'>
    <a href=''><img src='images/template_2_thumbnail.png' class='temp_thumb_2'></a>
   </div>
   <div id='template_1_text'>
   </div>
 </div> 
 <div id='template_3_hover'>
   <div id='template_3_display'>
    <a href=''><img src='images/template_1_thumbnail.png' class='temp_thumb_3'></a>
   </div>
   <div id='template_1_text'>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a proper _working_ code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by setting the container to relative. In addition to setting it was display:inline-flex. The z index now changes properly when activating the jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index doesn't work because your problem is with how the templates are positioned you can tell this because only the item to the right is being placed over the one that is enlarging.

You should take "float:left" off of all items. Then position the templates by giving their parent element "display:inline-flex"

Comment: I did this, and adjusted it and added this jquery but nothing works still    $("#template_1_wrapper").animate({
    "width" : '628px',
    "height" : 'auto',
    "zIndex" : '10000'
   });